# Migration didn't pluralize table name

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

I added a simple class `MemberModel` and added the following to my database context class:

```
public DBSet<MemberModel> Member { get; set; }
```

After adding migration and updating the database, the table name generated is `Member` and not `Members`. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EF Core will use the name of the DbSet property.  Rename `Member` to `Members` should result in a Members table.

```
public DBSet<MemberModel> Members { get; set; }
```

more info
https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/167